# Scene Builder 2.0 ignores controller

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I follow this example: http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-event-handling-examples/

And this is my controller:

```
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML //  fx:id="myButton"
    private Button myButton; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }    

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        // Button was clicked, do something...
        System.out.println("TEST");
    }
}
```

After that I open fxml file with scene builder. In the left bottom corner controller class is defined right. However I don't get auto complete for ids and event handlers. I mean I don't have any dropdowns like at image from that example.

[image]

I have a feeling that SB doesn't parse my controller only shows its name from xml file. How to fix it?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha But how can you explain the image I provided? Look at the dropdowns.

Comment: May be this works when the `fxml` is located in the **same package** as the `controller`. Though, I am not sure. May be someone can guide you better.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha you are completly right. If the fxml is in the same package, you'll get the dropdowns.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha You are right - must be in the same "folder". Make an answer and I will accept it. But I can't understand - `fxml` (resource) and `java` (source) must be different folders. How then to work? Move fxml to and fro?

Comment: @griFlo Do you know then how to work with them in real life? Move fxml to and fro?

Comment: @iJava I don't get your question. What do you mean by `move fxml to and fro`?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I mean that fxml file must be in src/main/resources and XController.java in src/main/java. This is the common practice as I undertand. But if we want SB to parse controller it means fxml and controlelr must be in same folder - so we either move controller to fxml folder or move fxml to controller folder.

Comment: @iJava I'didnt know till now, that there are dropdowns for that. Just put the fxml file wherever you want and write the value in yourself. I works. You dont need the dropdowns!!

Comment: @griFlo I undertstand you but wting by hands can lead to mistakes - you understand....

Comment: @iJava I understand you, but as it looks, there are two ways: 1) copy the file into the package where your controller is. 2) write the values in yourself (ctrl + c/ ctrl +v to avoid spelling errors)

Comment: @iJava Why do you say that the fxml and the java source must be in different folders? It's pretty common, especially in big apps, to create packages for each visual unit, containing the fxml, controller, and possibly even the css for that unit. This is how it's done in [SceneBuilder itself](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/44011b18f8ae/apps/scenebuilder/SceneBuilderApp), for example. Adam Bien uses this approach in his examples (see [Airhacks](https://github.com/AdamBien/airhacks-control), for example).

Comment: @James_D Thank you for your hint. By default netbeans created in different folders and I thought it's common practice.

Comment: @James_D I see you are expert in JavaFX. Could you take a look at this question and at least give some hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635824/javafx-binding-real-example-must-ejb-dto-be-completely-rewritten

Comment: Read it, but I don't know nearly enough EJB to offer anything useful.

Comment: @James_D See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKU7ZeCNbqU time 40:04 and 40:40 He open fxml file from /src/main/resources and controller is parsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dropdown` is visible beside the `controller textfield` and other `event-handling textfields` in the SceneBuilder only when the controller and the fxml are present in the **same folder**.

There are feature request already opened for them, please vote for them.

- [Controller class source code could also be searched in a source path](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/DTL-5573)
- [maven structure support](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/DTL-5124)

Comment: Only not in the `same package` but in the `same folder`.

Comment: See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKU7ZeCNbqU time 40:04 and 40:40 He open fxml file from /src/main/resources and controller is parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply go through on the following steps

1. open eclipse go to File->Other->JavaFX->JavaFX Project
2. Give the project name then click (without Finish button)Next->Next->Language->FXML
3. Finally project is created with SampleController then you can see Controller Class automatically added into SceneBuilder.
4. Just take a button then try to see now Code:On Action showing the method as well (If the method is written inside of SampleController class)